# Netlogo arrays need literal values

Tags: netlogo

The array is expecting a literal value

```
set chrom [forage_min forage_rate share_min share_rate mating_treshold]
        print chrom
```

How can I handle it? I really don't understand arrays in Netlogo.

Comment: https://subversion.american.edu/aisaac/notes/netlogo-basics.xhtml#list-creation

Answer (score 2):

(You speak of "arrays" in your question, but I think you mean "lists". It is possible to use arrays in NetLogo via the [`array` extension](https://ccl.northwestern.edu/netlogo/docs/array.html), but unless you have very specific needs, that's probably not what you want. So, assuming that you are trying to create a list:)

The square bracket syntax for declaring lists only works with "literal" values, e.g., raw strings or numbers. If you want to build a list out of variables or more complex expressions, you need to use the [`list`](http://ccl.northwestern.edu/netlogo/docs/dictionary.html#list) primitive. In your case, that would be something like:

```
set chrom (list forage_min forage_rate share_min share_rate mating_treshold)
```

I would encourage you to read the [**Lists** section of the NetLogo programming guide](https://ccl.northwestern.edu/netlogo/docs/programming.html#lists).