# Error: Expected a literal value - NetLogo

Tags: netlogo

I am unable to understand the following error: "expected a literal value". But, it is a literal value, why not accept it? Can someone help me?

Thanks

```
turtles-own [ metabolism reproduction ]


to setup 
      let list1 [ value1 value2 value3 ] ;; value1, value2 and value3 are global variables in interface (input numeric)
      let list2 [ number1 number2 number3 ] ;; number1, number2 and number3 are global variables in interface (input numeric)
      foreach list1 [ item1 ->
        foreach list2 [ item2 ->
          sprout-turtles 1  [            
            ask turtles [
              set metabolism item1
              set reproduction item2
              ;setxy random-xcor random-ycor
            ]
          ]
        ]
      ]
    ]
  ]

end
```

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43832803/netlogo-arrays-need-literal-values

Comment: Thanks Lena. Helped a lot :)

Comment: this is also in the NetLogo FAQ: http://ccl.northwestern.edu/netlogo/docs/faq.html#im-trying-to-make-a-list-why-do-i-keep-getting-the-error-expected-a-constant